# How to compare input text with database value in Spring Boot?

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, chart.js, thymeleaf

What I want to do: In html I input text (for example: 11:00:00). Then this input value will be compared with **column Time** in Database and display data relate to 11:00:00. I think I have to transmit input text from Html to Controller,save into a variable, then in Repository file,I use the syntax "Select ... from ... Where time = XXX",but I don't know how to do...

My table in SQL server is **product**,has 4 columns : **id**, **TAG00** (my temperature data), **Date**, **Time**.

Thanks for your help.

**AppController.java**

```
public class AppController {
@Autowired
private ProductService service; 
@Autowired
private ProductRepository prorepo;

@RequestMapping("/ChartBar")
public String viewBar(Model model) {
    List<Object[]> listData = service.listData(20);
    model.addAttribute("listData", listData);
    List<Object[]> listTime = service.listTime("20");
    model.addAttribute("listTime", listTime);
    return "ChartBar";
}
}
```

**ProductRepository.java**

```
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {

@Query(value="SELECT tag00 FROM Product",nativeQuery =true)
public List<Object[]> findByTag00(@Param("tag00")float tag00);

@Query(value="SELECT time FROM Product",nativeQuery =true)
public List<Object[]> findByTime(@Param("time")String time);}
```

**Product.java**

```
@Entity
public class Product {
public int id;
public float tag00;
public String date;
public String time;
protected Product() {
}
protected Product(int id, float tag00, String date, String time) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.tag00 = tag00;
    this.date = date;
    this.time = time;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public float getTAG00() {
    return tag00;
}
public void setTAG00(float tag00) {
    this.tag00 = tag00;
}
public String getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}   
public String getTime() {
    return time;
}
public void setTime(String time) {
    this.time = time;
}
}
```

**ChartBar.html** I use Graph (ChartJS) to display data & time from database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<div  style="position:relative;left:50px;top:5px;"  > <!-- Position: 
relative(tuong quan theo left,right,bottom,top), absolute,fixed -->
  <a href="/">Home</a>       
</div> 
<script 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.8.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@0.5.0"> 
</script> <!-- thu vien dung de hien thi gia tri tren bieu do -->
<div class="container">
<canvas id="ChartBar"></canvas>
</div>
<div class="container">
<canvas id="myChart1" width ="350" height="350"></canvas>
</div>
<script th:inline="javascript">
let myChart1 = document.getElementById('myChart1').getContext('2d');
// Global Options
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = 'Lato';
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = '#777';
let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart1, {
  type:'bar', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
  data:{
    //labels: [1,3,5,7];
    labels:/*[[${listTime}]]*/,<!--my Time data-->
    datasets:[{
      label:'Temperature',      
      //data: [2,4,6,8];
      data:/*[[${listData}]]*/, <!--my Temperature data-->         
      backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',              
      fill: false,
      borderWidth:1,
      borderColor:'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.6)', //thay doi mau cho Line
      hoverBorderWidth:1,
      hoverBorderColor:'#111',
      pointRadius: 3
    }]
  },
  options: {      
      legend : {
          display: false,
      },
      responsive :  true ,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,         
      plugins: { //plugin dung de hien thi gia tri len bieu do
          datalabels: {
                display: function(context) {
                    return context.dataIndex % 1; 
                },
                backgroundColor: function(context) {
                    return context.dataset.backgroundColor;
                },
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255,0)',
                borderRadius: 2,
                anchor : 'end',
                align : 'top',
                color: 'black',
                font: {
                    weight: 'bold'
                },
                formatter: Math.round
            }
        },
      scales: {//scales dung de cai dat option cho cot X,Y
          yAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  beginAtZero: true,
                  stepSize: 0.1,
                  min: 24,
                  max: 25,
                  fontColor : 'blue'
              },
          }],
          xAxes: [{
              ticks: {
                  fontColor: 'blue'
              },
          }]
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

**ProductRepository.java**

```java
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
    public List<Object[]> findByTag00Is(@Param("tag00")float tag00);
    public List<Object[]> findByTimeIs(@Param("time")float time2); 
}
```

`findByTimeIs(float time2)` this is the same as `Select ... from ... where time = time2`

**AppController.java**

```java
public class AppController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductService service; 
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository prorepo;

    @RequestMapping("/ChartLine")
    public String viewLine(Model model, @RequestParam(name="time", required=false)float time) {
        // do anything with time
        // example : propero.findByTimeIs(time);
    }
```

Comment: How about ChartLine.html? I need a textbox to input time,then compare time from html with time in Database...